# New Microsoft Mouse, Now Outlook Scroll Speed Slow

Tags: mouse, microsoft-outlook-2013, scrolling

**OS**: Windows 8.1
**Mouse**: Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic

I plugged in the mouse today, and even after adjusting both the Windows scroll speed settings in Control Panel and the settings within the "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" (which appears to be the Intellipoint replacement), the message list in Outlook 2013 scrolls **very very** slow. All other applications are affected positively by the increased scroll speed setting - the problem seems only to affect the message list in Outlook 2013. My old Microsoft Wireless 4000 mouse did not have this problem.

*I should clarify that when reading a message in the preview pane the scrolling speed is fine - the problem is just when scrolling through the message list.*.

EDIT: More details

- I went back and tried the old mouse and other mice I had on hand - they all scroll the message list just fine. New mouse; message list scrolls slowly/poorly
- I tried USB2 and USB3 ports, issue occurs on both

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this list very large?  Outlook can consume a large amount of memory if it is loading a very large inbox.

Comment: Note that the problem did not occur until plugging in the new mouse this morning. With the mouse I've been using for the last 4 years, it was not a problem. It wasn't a problem this morning at 8:00, but was a problem at 8:05 when I plugged the new mouse in.

Comment: If you plug in the old mouse now, is it, still a problem?  Unless you are using `"Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center` to actually configure behavior outside of a default mouse it really isn't require nor has it been updated in years.  So is that a new introduction?

Comment: I went back and tried the old mouse and other mice I had on hand - they all scroll the message list just fine. New mouse: message list scrolls slowly/poorly. Additionally, I tried USB2 and USB3 ports, issue occurs on both. The Mouse and Keyboard Center shows a graphic illustration of the new mouse and it's new features, so assuredly it's been updated to support it.

Comment: Are we talking magnitudes slower or just slower?

Comment: Magnitudes slower. As in, the list is basically unscrollable. I can scroll with all my might and all the speed my middle finger has, and the list barely moves.

Comment: I presume there isn't another system you can try the mouse on?  This device is relatively new?  The mouse itself is not a new product (2013) so I am just covering my basics.  The next step would be to start Outlook while in Safe Mode to see if that helps.

Comment: Couple things to try/check: Disable hardware acceleration in Outlook. Completely uninstall the Mouse and Keyboard Center (use generic Mouse drivers instead in needbe).

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the suggestion. I walked over and tested the mouse on a colleague's PC, and the scroll speed was nice and quick in the message window. We checked all the settings in his Mouse and Keyboard Center app, and everything appeared to be set normally. With this, I knew the issue lied solely on my end. I tried Outlook in Safe Mode to no avail. I did, however, install drivers again off Microsoft's web site and that appeared to resolve the issue. I didn't know why I didn't try that initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the mouse was first plugged in, a window appeared saying that it was installing the Mouse and Keyboard Center. Because of this, I was under the assumption that it was installing new drivers. Unfortunately, this assumption appeared to be incorrect. Installing the latest drivers available from Microsoft has resolved the scrolling issue in Outlook 2013.

**Driver Link**: http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/sculpt-ergonomic-mouse

Comment: I just reformatted and completed a clean installation of Windows 10. The issue of slow scrolling did not appear until several days after the Windows 10 install. Thankfully I remembered this post, installed the new Mouse and Keyboard Center to get the latest driver, and everything is back to normal again.

Comment: It appears outlook ignores the settings